# Linear transformation understanding

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, transformation, linear-transformations

Let $S: R^2 → R^2$ be the function defined by $S(x, y) = (x − y, y)$ for all $(x, y)$
I've found the matrix for this which was question 1.

These are the two questions I am struggling to understand.

(1) What does S do to horizontal lines of the form $y = a$ ?

(2) What does S do to vertical lines of the form $x = b$ ?

For (1) I can see that the line $y=a$ is projected to itself but there was something else in the memo which said that points on the x-axis are left unchanged. This is what I don't understand because for the transformation for the x co-ordinate it would be $x=x-a$. This would clearly no longer be on the x-axis.

I think what I really need is to understand how these linear maps affect the mapping of these line, and how to interpret the mapping with variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take a point $(x,a)$ on the line $y=a$. It becomes $(x-a,a)$. That is, the line shifts left by $a$ units (still the same line).
2. Take a point $(b,y)$ on the line $x=b$. It becomes $(b-y,y)=(b,0)+y(-1,1)$. The line rotates $45$ degrees positive around $(b,0)$ (draw the picture to see it).

Comment: Thank you I understand (1)

Comment: For 2 though, how does it become (b,0) + y(-1,1)

Comment: By definition: vector addition works componentwise $(a_1,b_1)+(a_2,b_2)=(a_1+a_2,b_1+b_2)$. Multiplication by a scalar is similar: $\lambda(a,b)=(\lambda a,\lambda b)$. But you don't really need it to understand the result, just look at $(b-y,y)$.